# How to edit/modify layer source in existing Leaflet map in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet, cartodb

I have created Leaflet map using Carto and React, as it is described here  https://github.com/IagoLast/cartojs-react-example, using:

```
const cartoSource = new carto.source.SQL(source);
const cartoStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(style);

this.layer = new carto.layer.Layer(cartoSource, cartoStyle);
client.getLeafletLayer().addTo(this.context.map);
```

Now i need to change this layer source dynamically somehow. Is it possible to change the layer source and how to do it? How to find specified layer from leaflet map? Or i need to delete this layer and create the new one?.

Comment: *Why* do you need to change the layer source *dynamically*? Can't you just create the map with the layer source you want?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to apply [`setQuery` method](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartosourcesqlsetquery) on your `cartoSource` object. If necessary, you would need to change the style.